# jQuery $.when(...).done(...) not working as desired

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a timing critical function that cannot be executed until a couple of Ajax calls have been completed. The Ajax calls issue requests from the server for data required to populate fields on initial page load.

My Ajax calls are working, but they are not completing before the critical function `GetUserDefaults()` is called. No matter where I set a breakpoint (using Firefox) I am seeing that `_MasterRules` is always initialized as expected, but without a breakpoint `GetUserDefaults()` gets called before `GetMasterRules()` is completed. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the code in document.ready?

Here is an example of my code:

```
_MasterRules = null;
_UserDefaults = null;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.when( GetMasterRules() )
    .done(function () { 
        GetUserDefaults()  // <<== MUST NOT call until GetMasterRules() is complete
    });
})

// Initialize Master Rules
function GetMasterRules() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/GetMasterRules",
        dataType: "json"
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        _MasterRules = data;
    })
}

// _MasterRules must be initialized before calling
function GetUserDefaults() {

    if (_MasterRules == null) {
        alert("_MasterRules == null");
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/GetUserDefaults",
        dataType: "json"
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        _UserDefaults = data;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code is not chaining / waiting on a deferred object as it is passing `undefined` to `$.when`.

Hint: *return* the deferred from `GetMasterRules`.

Comment: I've been reading the $.when documentation on jquery.com and I see a lot of mention about `Deferred` but I haven't been able to make sense of it. Would it be too involved to show me how this would be done as it pertains to the code I included above?

Comment: @rwkiii: In your code, you just need to do `return $.ajax({...`.

Comment: A jQuery 1.8+ Deferred is effectively an object that follows [Promises/A](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A) (well, mostly anyway) and a deferred is returned from `$.ajax`. The `$.when` function creates a new deferred object that waits for the supplied deferred objects (and in will in turn "done" or "fail"), which is why a deferred (ie. the deferred chain started by the AJAX call) needs to be supplied. An important point to note is that `.done` *also* returns a deferred object, which is why the function look as Rocket suggests.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Your answer helped me resolve this issue and taught me something important for my needs. Your answer is short, but precise. If you will submit an answer to this question I will mark it as correct. Thank you.

Comment: @rwkiii You can always submit your own answer :D